# Compare two folders on the basis of file names only

Tags: linux, comparison

**First** , let me explain my situation , I have been scraping images from a website to a local folder, I used OpenCV to apply pre-processing on said images and produced the processed images with exactly the same names in a different folder , The OpenCV script has failed towards the end and skipped a very small number of images , now I want to clean those images up from the scrapped images folder to have a 1:1 matching between the two .
**Second** ,  I tried using `diff` and reading about other questions but they all seem to be interested in comparing the files themselves , not just the names , of course I **know** that the files are different themselves , that's why I am only  interested in comparing their names .
So is there a way to do this ?
**EDIT**: I am **NOT** interested in comparing the file contents , only their names , so solutions interested in comparing two copies won't work for me .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In bash, how do I compare two folders to ensure they contain the same sets of files?](https://superuser.com/questions/1288356/in-bash-how-do-i-compare-two-folders-to-ensure-they-contain-the-same-sets-of-fi)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski that question is comparing two copies , aka it is interested in the contents of the files , I , however , am not .

Comment: At least two answers ignore contents.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes , I think you are right , I wasn't looking on the lower answers , however I think the question should remain to make it easier for searching later ? What do you think ? you know , instead of having the answer ambiguously hiding in the lower answers of a slightly different question.

Comment: Automated cleanup process is described [here](https://superuser.com/help/roomba). If I get it right, question closed as a duplicate will survive at least 365 days, unless it's downvoted.

Comment: I would close this question.  A quick google search found several existing answers

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/355310), "Should duplicates be deleted?" section. The question should be closed as duplicate. It doesn't necessarily mean it will be deleted.